# Merge two JS key value arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I need to merge two JS arrays, but using concat fn or lodash library i can't do it...

I have two arrays like these:

```
[ test2: 'string', test: 'string' ]

[ nome: 'string',test2: 'string', test: 'string' ]
```

And what i need is to have result array like this:

```
[ test2: 'string', test: 'string', nome: 'string' ]
```

How can i do this? i tried several methods withouth success...

Array concat doesn't work...

Thanks

Comment: Those aren't arrays (nor any kind of valid JS literals)

Comment: These are not arrays. What you show is an object.

Comment: @VLAZ not even...

Comment: Ok, and how can i merge two objects like these?

Comment: so if you were to make them valid objects by using the `{key: value}`, what one gets overwritten, 1 or 2?

Comment: They are not objects either. Objects are denoted with `{}` in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj1 = { 'test2': 'string', 'test': 'string' };

var obj2 = { 'nome': 'string','test2': 'string', 'test': 'string' };

const object3 = {...obj1, ...obj2 }

console.log(object3)
```

> If both objects have a property with the same name, then the second
>   object property overwrites the first.

Answer (score 0):

You're using arrays as a key:value pair, but in Javascript that data type is an object. Your two inputs turned into objects look like this:

```
{ test2: 'string', test: 'string' }

{ nome: 'string', test2: 'string', test: 'string' }
```

To merge these two objects you can use the ECMAScript 2018 [Object Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax.

```
const obj1 = { test2: 'string', test: 'string' };
const obj2 = { nome: 'string',test2: 'string', test: 'string' };
const newObj = {...ob1, ...ob2}
```

Note that because your objects share the same name and value pairs, there is only one copy of `test:'string'` and `test2:'string'`